# Stormcrawl with SQL external module gets ParseFilters exception at crawl sage

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I use Stromcrawler with SQL external module. I have updated my pop.xml with:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-crawler-sql</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I use similar injector/crawl procedure as in the case with ES setup:

```
storm jar target/stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --local sql-injector.flux --sleep 864000
```

I have created mysql database `crawl`, table `urls` and successfully injected my urls in it. For example, If I do `select * from crawl.urls limit 5;`, I can see urls, status, and other fields. From this, I conclude that at this stage, the crawler connects to the database.

Sql-injector looks like this:

```
name: "injector"

includes:
- resource: true
  file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
  override: false

- resource: false
  file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
  override: true

- resource: false
  file: "sql-conf.yaml"
  override: true

- resource: false
  file: "my-config.yaml"
  override: true

components:
 - id: "scheme"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.StringTabScheme"
constructorArgs:
  - DISCOVERED

spouts:
 - id: "spout"
  className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.FileSpout"
parallelism: 1
constructorArgs:
  - "seeds.txt"
  - ref: "scheme"

bolts:
- id: "status"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.sql.StatusUpdaterBolt"
parallelism: 1

streams:
 - from: "spout"
to: "status"
grouping:
  type: CUSTOM
  customClass:
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.URLStreamGrouping"
    constructorArgs:
      - "byHost"
```

When I run:

```
storm jar target/stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --remote sql-crawler.flux
```

I got the following exception at the Parse bolt:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception caught while loading the        ParseFilters from parsefilters.json at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.ParseFilters.fromConf(ParseFilters.java:67) at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt.prepare(JSoupParserBolt.java:116) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5043$fn__5056.invoke(executor.clj:803) at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to build JSON object from file at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.ParseFilters.(ParseFilters.java:92) at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.ParseFilters.fromConf(ParseFilters.java:62) ... 5 more Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name...

[Screenshot of StormUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8YUA.png)

sql-crawler.flux:

```
name: "crawler"

includes:
- resource: true
  file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
  override: false

- resource: false
  file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
  override: true

- resource: false
  file: "sql-conf.yaml"
  override: true

- resource: false
  file: "my-config.yaml"
  override: true

spouts:
- id: "spout"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.sql.SQLSpout"
parallelism: 100

bolts:
- id: "partitioner"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt"
parallelism: 1
- id: "fetcher"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt"
parallelism: 1
- id: "sitemap"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt"
parallelism: 1
- id: "parse"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt"
parallelism: 1
- id: "status"
className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.sql.StatusUpdaterBolt"
parallelism: 1


streams:
- from: "spout"
to: "partitioner"
grouping:
  type: SHUFFLE

- from: "partitioner"
to: "fetcher"
grouping:
  type: FIELDS
  args: ["key"]

- from: "fetcher"
to: "sitemap"
grouping:
  type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

- from: "sitemap"
to: "parse"
grouping:
  type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

- from: "fetcher"
to: "status"
grouping:
  type: FIELDS
  args: ["url"]
  streamId: "status"

- from: "sitemap"
to: "status"
grouping:
  type: FIELDS
  args: ["url"]
  streamId: "status"

- from: "parse"
to: "status"
grouping:
  type: FIELDS
  args: ["url"]
  streamId: "status"
```

It looks like object `StringUtils` at ParseFilters.java:60 is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the content of *src/main/resources.parsefilters.json* (or whichever value you might have set for *parsefilters.config.file*), judging by the error message, the JSON it contains is not valid. Don't forget to rebuild the uber jar with `mvn clean package`

Comment: Thanks, Julien.  just replace the parsefilter.json file with the version from the github and this issue is solved. However, I got another one within the same crawl-sql implementation. Can I post it here as another answer or open a new question?

Comment: sorry just saw your comment. I have replied to your other question. Thanks!