# StormCrawler SQL error for column 'nextfetchdate'

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

My setup is identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483996/stormcrawl-with-sql-external-module-gets-parsefilters-exception-at-crawl-sage). When I run crawler in the crawl mode, I got the following error:

> [Thread-130-status-executor[109 109]] ERROR c.d.s.p.AbstractStatusUpdaterBolt - Exception caught when storing
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2099-12-31 00:00:00' for column 'nextfetchdate' at row 1
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3964) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.sql.StatusUpdaterBolt.store(StatusUpdaterBolt.java:132) ~[stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.persistence.AbstractStatusUpdaterBolt.execute(AbstractStatusUpdaterBolt.java:196) [stromcrawler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5043$tuple_action_fn__5045.invoke(executor.clj:739) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4964.invoke(executor.clj:468) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4475.onEvent(disruptor.clj:41) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:509) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:487) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:74) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5043$fn__5056$fn__5109.invoke(executor.clj:861) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]

Please, advice where to look to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the [fetch interval for errors](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/crawler-conf.yaml#L64) which has been set to -1, which means 'never revisit'. This is actually translated into a date long into the future by the [DefaultScheduler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/persistence/DefaultScheduler.java#L39). Not clear why mysql chokes on it. You could try setting a more reasonable value e.g. 43200 for a month and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, replacing -1 with your suggestion worked and also the same had to be done for the `fetchInterval.default` parameter.

Comment: I see that my crawl have started to fetch some data but I don't get the content. Could you advise would it be possible to append a column with the fetched content? Thanks

Comment: The SQL module contains resources for storing the status of the URLs, not their content, which is done with indexing bolts in other modules. Look at https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/bolt/IndexerBolt.java for a source of inspiration. If you can contribute an indexer for SQL, that would be very welcome!